# Ansible installed from source - what should my library setting be?

Tags: ansible

I have installed Ansible from source as per the instructions at:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html

However when I try to use any command other than `script`, I get the following error:

```
fatal: [...]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! The module get_url was not found in configured module paths"}
```

If the source Ansible directory is `/home/cloud/ansible`, and I have done a `make install`, what should I set the `library` path setting to in ansible.cfg?

Comment: Did you really clone the repository recursive? A module-not-found error points into direction it was not cloned with the submodules. `git clone --recursive ...`

Comment: Yep I did, and I retried with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @udondan says, make sure you used:

```
git clone https://github.com/ansible/ansible --recursive
```

to clone the Ansible repo, and then run:

```
cd ./ansible
source ./hacking/env-setup
```

You don't need to run `make install`.

The machine that has Ansible running on it needs some other Python modules too, they are listed at the bottom of the http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#running-from-source section. Best to install the `pip` Python package manager with:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

and then install the required packages:

```
sudo pip install paramiko PyYAML Jinja2 httplib2 six
```

Comment: I did clone recursive, but to be sure I nuked and re-did exactly as per the above. Still no joy. Oddly enough, `win_get_url` works fine, but `get_url` doesn't. I'll be happy to add any extra info!

Comment: Strange that `win_get_url` works, as it's a core module too.

Are you running Ansible on a Windows machine?

Comment: It's running on Oracle Linux (don't ask) 7.1.1 which is based on CentOS. I take it there's nothing I need to do to the machine being deployed to? Is there any way to debug these sorts of problems?

Comment: It's ok my work env uses Oracle linux boxes too :) I updated my answer.

Comment: OK I have found the problem, and as I suspected, it was my own incompetence. I was using dynamic inventory, and I had a Windows cloud instance that was incorrectly tagged, and Ansible was trying to run `get_url` against that Windows instance. (I think the error message is confusing in this situation, but hey). I've accepted your answer since it sums up some very useful information, and also provides a checklist for future folks like me when diagnosing these sorts of issues. Many thanks for all your input on this one!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Cheers!